# Powershell 7zip not extracting 2nd and subsequent files

Tags: powershell-3.0, 7zip

Here's my code:

```
set-alias sz "$env:ProgramFiles\7-Zip\7z.exe"
$7zf = "first.7z"
$7zp = "password1"
sz e $7zf "-p$7zp" $7zo
$7zf = "second.7z"
$7zp = "password2"
sz e $7zf "-p$7zp" $7zo
```

*it's not elegant but with 50+ files, elegant takes the backseat to utility

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

found out the second password was breaking the script because the actual password had a $